# validate_email python library working on local machine but not on aws elasticbean

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, email-validation

validate_email is a python library to verify if an email exists or not.
I have been using it in my local machine for a long time but when I made a web app using django,and hosted it on aws elasticbean.

It is not able to validate and always returns None.Code is:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
choice="someoneeg@somedomain.com"    
is_valid = validate_email(choice,verify=True)
```

I suspect if it is problem of some port or some firewall issue ,I have tried adding http listener at port 25 but still it didn't work.
I also tried directly using the validate.py file of the developer which is available on github ,still results are same (I have validate_email and Py3DNS installed as required)

Answer (score 2):

Check *inbound rules* for your ec2 instance created by ElasticBeanstalk

Dont start your *http* port on `25` do it on port `80`. You can also try this

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import validate_email

def validate(email):
    try:
        validate_email(email)
        return true
    except ValidationError:    
        return false
```